# Detecting an app installation on iPhone is failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify

I am trying to check whether `Spotify` is installed on iPhone with my code and `Spotify` is already installed on my device. However its always in `else` block in code below

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify://"]]) {
    //open spotify
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify://"]];
}
else
{
    [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Spotify was not installed"];
    [SVProgressHUD dismissWithDelay:1.00];
}
```

However I can successfully open Spotify with the code below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify://"]];
```

I am wondering why `canOpenURL` is not working for `Spotify` while it works for `Apple Music` with `music://` URL Scheme.

Comment: Did you add "spotify" to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`?

Comment: Any messages in the console when you use `canOpenURL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
                 [NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify://"]])

            {
                NSLog(@"App Found");
            }
 else
            {
                NSLog(@"App Not Found");
            }
```

If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare the URL schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by adding the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key to your app's Info.plist file. If you call this method for a scheme not declared using that key, this method always returns false, whether or not an appropriate app is installed. To learn more about the key, see **[LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl)**.